# Getting the last part of a list element in java

Tags: java, string, list, text

I want to develop a small program which reads a text file and stores the values into a list. The list has the following format:

```
[1234 nick, 243 56475, 13 mi87ke]
```

What I want to accomplish, is to extract only the last part of each list's elements. Despite the fact that I have considered two different approaches, I'm still not getting correct results.

My code so far is the following:

```
 First approach:
        index = randomGenerator.nextInt(list.size());
        element = list.get(index);
        while (element.length() < 6 || element.length() > 8) {
             index = randomGenerator.nextInt(list.size());
             element = list.get(index).substring(element.lastIndexOf(" ")+1);  
        }

Second approach:
        index = randomGenerator.nextInt(list.size());
        element = list.get(index);
        while (element.length() < 6 || element.length() > 8) {
             index = randomGenerator.nextInt(list.size());
             element = list.get(index);
             String[] bits = element.split(" ");
             element = bits[bits.length-1];
        }
```

Output from both approaches is the same:

```
leslie02
yakumo
Buddy1
yaseen
24 19871
```

I noticed that elements with length < 6 are still printed by returning the first part along with the second. Anyone knows why this happens and if there is a way to fix it?

Comment: care to explain the purpose of your odd while loop?

Comment: It is not really clear what you are asking; you would have to explain more clearly how input and expected output correlate. And it that sense, your answer isn't really helpful either. If nobody understands the question but you, nobody will care about the answer.

Comment: It was only because I was interested in elements that their length >= 6 and <= 8. This is what I got wrong from the beginning as I evaluated the element without separating the first 2 parts before the while loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to my question:

```
    index = randomGenerator.nextInt(list.size());
    element = list.get(index);
    String[] bits = element.split(" ");
    element = bits[bits.length-1];
    while (element.length() < 6 || element.length() > 8) {
         index = randomGenerator.nextInt(list.size());
         element = list.get(index);
         bits = element.split(" ");
         element = bits[bits.length-1];
    }
```

Comment: Care to explain how this solves the problem? Could be useful for other readers to be able to understand.

Comment: In my initial approach I did not extract the last part of the element before the while loop, so it returned with the first part also. If the first with the second part had a length satisfying the condition, it would be printed as correct. With the above modification, I extracted the last part of the element before the while loop, so the program now achieves what I had in mind from the start.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense.